# How to install Elasticsearch-head without internet

Tags: elasticsearch

I have downloaded the .zip file from mobz/elasticsearch-head for the installation of elasticsearch-head but don't know how to install it and where to place it in Linux server.
Can somebody help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to install that plugin from the file system, you can follow a [simple procedure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/installation.html#_custom_url_or_file_system).

Simply run this from within the `ES_HOME` folder:

```
sudo bin/plugin install file:///path/to/mobzhead.zip
```